# ERROR:root:Error running query: RequestError(400, u'parsing_exception', u'no [query] registered for [not]')

Tags: elasticsearch-6, elastalert, metricbeat

I am using `metricbeat-6.4.0`, `elasticsearch-6.4.0`, `elastalert-0.1.35`
I want to set email alerts when any process, suppose notepad++.exe is stopped.

Below is my rule:

```
realert:  
minutes: 60  
from_addr: appmonProcess@company.com  
alert_text: "Dear User,\n\t notepad++.exe is not running on server IN-MUM-EADMTOOL for the last 15 minutes"  
es_host: linux-a2adm.in.company.com  
index: metricbeat-6.4.0-*  
smtp_host: ismtp.corp.company.com  
type: frequency  
es_port: 29200  
filter:  
term:  
beat.hostname: IN-MUM-EADMTOOL  
not:  
term:  
system.process.name: notepad++.exe  
timeframe:  
minutes: 15  
alert: email  
name: 93__server__IN-MUM-EADMTOOL__system.process.name__eqnotepad++.exe__1__15  
email: ["aviral.srivastava@company.com"]  
num_events: 1
```

I am getting below error:

`INFO:elastalert:Starting up`
`WARNING:elasticsearch:GET http://linux-a2adm.in.company:29200/metricbeat-6.4.0-*/_search?_source_include=%40timestamp%2C%2A&ignore_unavailable=true&scroll=30s&size=10000 [status:400 request:0.035s]`
**`ERROR:root:Error running query: RequestError(400, u'parsing_exception', u'no [query] registered for [not]')`**
`INFO:elastalert:Ran 93__server__IN-MUM-EADMTOOL__system.process.name__eqnotepad++.exe__1__15 from 2018-11-09 17:18 India Standard Time to 2018-11-09 17:29 India Standard Time: 0 query hits (0 already seen), 0 matches, 0 alerts sent`
`INFO:elastalert:Sleeping for 59.895 seconds`

Answer (score 0):

Issue with the filter, try using:

```
filter:
-and:
 - term:
    beat.hostname: "IN-MUM-EADMTOOL"
 - not:
    term:
     system.process.name: "notepad++.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Elasticsearch Version > 5, this filter will not work writing queries embedding filters in *and*, *not*, *or* keywords. Instead, you can use *query key* to write the complete query.

```
filter:
 - query:
      query_string:
        query: " beat.hostname: IN-MUM-EADMTOOL AND NOT system.process.name: notepad++.exe"
```

[Relevant Documentation](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/writing_filters.html#negation-and-or) states that the kind of filter you have written using keywords like *and*, *not* only works for Elasticsearch 2.X or earlier